No Docker Compose file found in directory '/workspace/.'
I am using paketo buildpack for creating a docker image of my spring boot application using the below command:
gradlew bootBuildImage
It has successfully build the image with below message:
Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/employee-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
Inside my spring boot application I have a docker compose file named compose.yaml in the root to spin a mysql container. The contents of the file is given as below:
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employeeservice
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234

I am also using spring boot docker compose support in my project to fetch the mysql connection properties from the compose file.
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose'
But when I run the image using the below command
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=int" docker.io/library/employee-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
It is giving the below error:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-12-20T15:13:21.369Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.p.employee.EmployeeServiceApplication  : Starting EmployeeServiceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.5 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
2024-12-20T15:13:21.371Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.p.employee.EmployeeServiceApplication  : The following 1 profile is active: "int"
2024-12-20T15:13:21.624Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Docker Compose file found in directory '/workspace/.'
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.getComposeFile(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:149) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:109) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:433) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.purbarun.employee.EmployeeServiceApplication.main(EmployeeServiceApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[workspace/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[workspace/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[workspace/:na]

I am using Docker Desktop 4.37.1 and also note that I don't have any Dockerfile to create the image. I am using paketo buildpack to create the image.
I looked into similar threads given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77006121/no-docker-compose-file-found-in-directory but I am not convinced with the answers given sine I am using spring boot docker compose support.
Can anyone elaborate me why I am facing this issue and what's the way around.
Thanks in advance!

There are a couple of problems with what you're trying to do.

The first is Spring Boot & buildpacks related. When you package your application into a container, your build system runs and produces a JAR/WAR. Then Spring Boot's tools take that and passes it to buildpacks to run and generate a container from the JAR/WAR.
This means that ONLY the contents of your JAR/WAR will end up in the container (under /workspace) and files will exist in the same path structure as in your JAR/WAR in the container under /workspace.
tl;dr if you want something in the container, you need to make sure that it's in your JAR file.
You can run jar tf <file.jar> to check what is inside the JAR/WAR produced by a local build without buildpacks. That is what will end up in your container and it will end up at the same location as in that file, just under /workspace.

You are running your application in a container. From inside the container, your application cannot talk to the Docker host and have it initiate other containers (at least by default). That is a basic security limitation and it's there to protect you.
What you would typically do, and I would recommend, is make a second Docker compose file for production. In that, define a service for your app using the image you generated and any additional services that the app requires, like a database. You can then docker compose up and run your app and all its services.
I suggest keeping the production & development compose files separately. That's a personal preference/organization thing. You don't necessarily have to, you could use a profile in the compose file to use the same file but only have the app start when a profile is enabled. It's really your choice on how you want to structure things.



I was analyzing your response in more depth specifically the #1 point that you mentioned.  What I understood is that spring-boot-docker-compose is the somewhat the culprit since it looks for the compose.yaml file at application bootup which is not included in the jar as it was working when used from eclipse ide but starts failing when used from jar. That comes to my question which is does Docker Compose support in Spring Boot only works in local development using ide. What`s the work around I need to follow or if there is any way I can mount the .yaml file in \workspace directory

I can't make any official statement on it, but the docs list Spring Boot's Docker Compose support as a "development time" feature, so I'd say the focus is on making this work when you're developing applications and not for deployment/production. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/dev-services.html#features.dev-services.docker-compose

any way I can mount the .yaml file in \workspace directory -> Yes, but even if you could. See 2.) from my initial response. Your app will be running inside a container. To launch another container, you'd need to either expose your Docker daemon to the container (very bad for security) or you'd need to run Docker inside Docker, which is making this all way more complicated than it needs to be.

Yes, I got your point but forgetting about the docker and container stuffs, even when I just run the jar in my local using java -jar cmd it will still not work. I was thinking if I can do at least that.

Ah, I follow. Yes, that's a case where it could work. Idk if that's something that's intended to work, you could try opening an issue and see what someone from the Boot team has to say.
